# How can i use SQLLoader to load data into my Database tables directly from a tar.gz file?

Tags: database, oracle, tar, sql-loader, gzip

I am trying to load data into my oracle database table from an external tar.gz file. I can load data easily from a standard text file using SQLLoader but i'm not sure how to do the same if i have a tar.gz file instead of a word file.

I am found the following link somewhat helpful:

http://www.simonecampora.com/blog/2010/07/09/how-to-extract-and-load-a-whole-table-in-oracle-using-sqlplus-sqlldr-named-pipes-and-zipped-dumps-on-unix/

However the author of the link is using .dat.gz instead of .tar.gz. Is there anyway to load data into my Oracle database table using SQL loader from a tar.gz file instead of a text file?

Also, Part of the problem for me is that i'm supposed to load data from a NEW tar.gz file every hour into the same table. For e.g. In hour 1 i have file1.tar.gz and i load all its 10 rows of data into TABLE in my oracle database. In hour 2 i have file2.tar.gz and i have to load its 10 rows of data into the same TABLE in my oracle database. But the 10 rows extracted by SQLLoader in file2.tar.gz keep replacing the first 10 rows extracted from file1.tar.gz. Any way i can save the rows from file1.tar.gz as row 1-10 and file2.tar.gz rows as row 11-20 using SQL Loader?

Comment: Does the tar contain a single text file, or several files, or directories containing files?

Comment: @AlexPoole Single Text file. Part of the problem for me is that i'm supposed to load data from a NEW tar.gz file every hour into the same table.

For e.g. In hour 1 i have file1.tar.gz and i load all its 10 rows of data into TABLE in my oracle database. In hour 2 i have file2.tar.gz and i have to load its 10 rows of data into the same TABLE in my oracle  database. But the 10 rows extracted by SQLLoader in file2.tar.gz keep replacing the first 10 rows extracted from file1.tar.gz. 

Any way i can save the rows from file1.tar.gz as row 1-10 and file2.tar.gz rows as row 11-20 using SQL Loader?

Comment: Please add that information to the question rather than as a comment; also add your control file. I guess you have `truncate` or `replace`, rather than `append`?

Comment: @AlexPoole Yup, i had truncate in my control file. I replaced it with append and got the intended result. Many tanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magic is in the "zcat" part. zcat can output from zipped files. Including tar.gz.

For example try: zcat yourfile.tar.gz and you will see output. In the example URL you provided, they're redirecting the output of zcat into a place that SQLLDR can read from.

Comment: Hmmm Thanks, this is pretty useful

Part of the problem for me is that i'm supposed to load data from a NEW tar.gz file every hour into the same table. For e.g. In hour 1 i have file1.tar.gz and i load all its 10 rows of data into TABLE in my oracle database. In hour 2 i have file2.tar.gz and i have to load its 10 rows of data into the same TABLE in my oracle database. But the 10 rows extracted by SQLLoader in file2.tar.gz keep replacing the first 10 rows extracted from file1.tar.gz. Any way i can save the rows from file1.tar.gz as row 1-10 and file2.tar.gz rows as row 11-20 using SQL Loader?

Comment: Yeah if you use the example you posted in the URL, this will append the rows, rather than truncate so you will get 1-10 file1, 11-20 file 2, 21-30 file 3. etc.

Comment: Yup, my original control file had a truncate in it which i didn't notice. Replacing it with append resolved the issue. Thanks a bunch!